# Multiples Imagebutton to multiple activities

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to make my first app on Android Studio.

It will have 44 imagebuttons in the MainActivity and each imagebutton will have a kind of ClickListener that will open the chraracter activity with their informations.

I need help with how to configure the ClickListener and will be necessary create 44 activities?

What's is the easiest way to make this kind of app?

MainActivity Design:

[image: MainActivity]

Actually the image I put as a background of the MainActivity,  then I created invisibles imagebuttons to each character.

Comment: Grid view can help . But the image you posted is not exactly in grid alignment . So you need to find a way for that.

Comment: No, you will not need 44 activities. Your data should be separate from your view so you will probably use an [adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) to change the information displayed in a single activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real image is here, that was just for example, I already created imagebuttons for each character, I just wanted to click in each one and open a new activity with each character moves.

I just don't know how can I pass an image to the other acitivty to open the image to each character.

I tried using intent.putExtra but the value is replaced when the other activity starts (getIntExtra() and I can't open each image of the character.

[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR1Cv.jpg)

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        switch (v.getId()) {

               case R.id.rugal:

                   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovesActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra("RUGAL", R.drawable.rugal_moves);
                   startActivity(intent);
              break;

            case R.id.kusanagi:

                break;


    }
```

Edit: Already finished the app using other ways.